# How do I deploy a Tycho-built p2 repository to Artifactory?

Tags: deployment, artifactory, tycho, p2

The Artifactory doc [explains](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/P2+Repositories#P2Repositories-IntegrationwithTychoPlugins) how to use an existing repo in the build to resolve but not how to deploy one in the first place.

Comment: Are you asking for instructions on how to create a P2 repository in Artifactory?

Comment: No. The repo exists. I'm asking how to deploy to it.